# Rails set session var from array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays

I am returning some results from an external source where:

```
session[:response]['cpm_by_volxs'] == [ 0.0416, 0.0411, ..., 0.0335, 0.0333 ]
```

How could I then store just the first number `0.0416` as a different session var:

```
session[:somethingElse] = 0.0416
```

in a dynamic way (the response will always be different)?

I have tried:

```
 temp = session[:response]['cpm_by_volxs']
 session[:somethingElse] = temp[temp.index(1)]
```

**UPDATE**

Based on Ben Taitelbaum's suggestion:

```
<%= session[:Response]['cpm_by_volxs'][0] %> == [
<%= session[:Response]['cpm_by_volxs'][1] %> == 0
<%= session[:Response]['cpm_by_volxs'][2] %> == .
<%= session[:Response]['cpm_by_volxs'][3] %> == 0
<%= session[:Response]['cpm_by_volxs'][4] %> == 4
<%= session[:Response]['cpm_by_volxs'][5] %> == 1
<%= session[:Response]['cpm_by_volxs'][6] %> == 6
```

etc. Any how I can return this in one go? (I am  not able to change the response in any way).

Answer (score 1):

You can index into an array in ruby just as you would with other languages, so the first number is just `session[:response]['cpm_by_volxs'][0]`, which is the same as `temp[0]` in your example.

Comment: It appears your session variable is storing a string "[ 0.0416, ..." rather than an array, which is why indexing into it isn't giving you what you want. If you really can't change this, then consider parsing `session[:response]['cpm_by_volxs']` into an array via a regex.